# Mock objects calling final classes static methods with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I just started mocking different layers of our application. I came to  a point where one of my mock objects is returning NPE when it calls a final class static method. Is there a way around this?

e.g.

```
when(mockObject.someMethod(FinalClass.staticMethod(someParam)).anotherMethodCall)
    .thenReturn("someString");
```

Comment: Mockito cannot mock final methods in general; however, I doubt that even removing `final` will help here...

Comment: It is not possible with mockito to mock final classes or statis method. Although, i think you can do that with power mock. Maybe you can have a look http://code.google.com/p/powermock/

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion, I have updated my code snippet. kindly check it out

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use PowerMock and Mockito together.

I don't understand what your code snippet is trying to do, but the following snippets allow the static `getInstance()` method of the `Calendar` class to return a mocked `Calendar` Object. Maybe that'll point you in the right direction

At the class level:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Calendar.class)
public class XXXXXX {
```

In your test method:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Calendar.class);
    Calendar calendar = mock(Calendar.class);
    when(calendar.get(eq(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))).thenReturn(3);

    Mockito.when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(calendar);
```

Comment: What if my class has annotated with `@RunWith(Theories.class)`?

Answer (score 2):

Mockito doesn't support mocking a final class.Have a look at [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/).It allows you to mock static methods and classes. It can work with Mockito, [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) explains how to do that.

Comment: doesn't matter, Mockito cant mock Final classes

Comment: so you mean it is mocking a final class? I thought it is just calling the static method of a final class