# Mocking a class which has a static final field initialised in an unsafe manner

Tags: java

Problem:

In order to test a given class I need to be able to mock `ClassWithBadStaticFinalField`

I am unable to modify `ClassWithBadStaticFinalField`

Mocking `ClassWithBadStaticFinalField` with mockito is not possible because it attempts to interact with production servers when initialising its bad static final field

I have attempted to hack the field in the manner described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23200308/658663) but that fails with the following stacktrace

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError    
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)    
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)    
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:140)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1057)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1038)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)    
    at com.example.SomeTest.setFinalStatic(SomeTest.java:76)    
    at com.example.SomeTest.setUp(SomeTest.java:23)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)    
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)    
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)    
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)    
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)    
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)    
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)    
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)    
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)    
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)    
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)    
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)    
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)    
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)    
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)    
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)    
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)    
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    
    at com.example.ClassWithBadStaticFinalField.<clinit>(ClassWithBadStaticFinalField.java:17)    
    ... 34 more
```

ClassWithBadStaticFinalField.java

```
public abstract class ClassWithBadStaticFinalField {
    protected static final String SOME_STRING = SomeRidiculousClass.someInsaneStaticMethodWhichDoesBadThings();

    public ClassWithBadStaticFinalField() { // line 17

    }

    ...
}
```

I have requested that `ClassWithBadStaticFinalField` have an interface created which details all public methods, and so gets me out of this problem, but wheels turn slowly..

When the production servers are not available  `SomeRidiculousClass.someInsaneStaticMethodWhichDoesBadThings()` null pointers

I would rather not have to intercept the outbound call made from `SomeRidiculousClass.someInsaneStaticMethodWhichDoesBadThings()` and force a response back.

Comment: How about mocking the `someInsaneStat....` method? Static method can also be mocked, even if not as simply.

Comment: Mocking a static method, which is used in a class that is the thing you actually want to mock, seems a bit of a roundabout way of doing things

Comment: What's wrong with a roundabout way, exactly? I thought it was already understood that there are no straightforward solutions available to you.

Comment: If no straightforward way is available there is nothing wrong with using a roundabout way of doing things if it is the onylavailable optin. Obviously I'd prefer something straightforward; as far as I'm aware there's no direct method available, but I certainly don't know everything - hence the question