# EasyMock is calling the real method

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I have this test case:

**TestClient**

```
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class TestClient extends EasyMockSupport {

    @TestSubject
    private final IClient client = new Client();

    @Mock
    private HttpClient httpClient;

    @Mock
    private HttpUriRequest request;
    @Mock
    private HttpResponse response;

    @Test
    public void testExecute() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        expect(httpClient.execute(request)).andReturn(response);
        replayAll();
        httpClient.execute(request);
        client.execute(request);
        verifyAll();
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
public class Client implements IClient {

    private final HttpClient httpClient;

    public Client() {
        httpClient = createDefaultClient();
    }

    private HttpClient createDefaultClient() {
        return HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse execute(final HttpUriRequest request)
            throws IOException {
        return httpClient.execute(request);
    }

}
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Unexpected method call HttpUriRequest.getURI()
```

Normally the created will not call this method.

Why I get this error? Why it require me to define a result for `getURI` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove `final` from

> ```
> private final HttpClient httpClient;
> ```

Otherwise EasyMock cannot overwrite your `httpClient` with its own mocked instance.  Of course better still would be to directly use dependency injection, but that's tangential to your actual issue.

You *can* use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19426999/113632) as a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9697531/113632); but dear me no...

---

*Original answer:*

Posting a full stack trace, and relevant parts of your `Client` class would help us debug this with you.  You mention that:

> in `client.execute(request)` I do `httpClient.execute(request)`.

But (at least in the code you've posted) nowhere does `client` get a reference to the mocked `httpClient` instance.  Does your `Client` class perhaps construct it's own `HttpClient` instance, and make requests against *that* instead of your mock?

If so, your `Client` should follow the [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern and pass in an `HttpClient` instance at construction, rather than construct one internally.

Another possibility is that your `Client.execute()` method is calling `request.getURI()` at some point, in which case you simply need to `expect()` a call to `request.getURI()`.

Comment: The mocked `httpClient` will be injected by EasyMock (that why I use `TestSubject` annotation). I agree it is not visible if we don't know the framework.

Comment: @user230137 please include your `Client` code so we can see what it's doing.  If you make a call to `new HttpClient()` anywhere in `Client` that will be used even though EasyMock is injecting.

Comment: I added the client code. When removing final it works but perhaps there's a solution to that.

Comment: And even if I call `request.getURI()` in my `Client.execute()` it should work because it will not call it as the method is mocked.

Comment: @user230137 Yes, the issue is your `final httpClient` instance variable.  Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that inside of the method `client.execute(request)` there is a `request.getURI()` statement (or buried deeply in called methods). Easy Mock needs to know the response to give when this method is called.

Comment: in `client.execute(request)` I do `httpClient.execute(request)`. Why EasyMock needs to know the response for `getURI` method? I have created an expectation for method. It isn't the point of mocking?

Comment: @user230137 it would help if you posted the contents of `Client.execute()`; otherwise we can only speculate.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is the call of `httpClient.execute(request);`. Try to remove it. You already setup a expectation for the `httpClient` via `expect(httpClient.execute(request)).andReturn(response);`.

```
@Test
public void testExecute() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    expect(httpClient.execute(request)).andReturn(response);
    replayAll();
    client.execute(request);
    verifyAll();
}
```

Comment: No it's not  that. EasyMock failed to inject my mock as the field is final but failed silently