# Mockito with static methods in util classes

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I tried to find but couldnt get what i was looking for. Is it possible to do something like following in mockito?

```
when(TestServiceUtil.getTestItem()).thenReturn(someItem);
```

Comment: Mokito can't do that on it's own, but can if you use it with PowerMock. See if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083432/mockito-mock-objects-calling-final-classes-static-methods/17084152#17084152

Comment: You can also read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482315/why-does-mockito-not-mock-static-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pom.xml, add the following dependencies:

`<dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.6</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.6</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>`

above your test class:
`@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class YourClassName`

[...]

    `@Before
    public void beforeTest() throws SQLException {
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(TestServiceUtil.class);`

Now you can use (as you had it):
`when(TestServiceUtil.getTestItem()).thenReturn(someItem);`

Last words - don't overuse PowerMockito. Focus on clean, object oriented code.