# Mocking Unmarshaller

Tags: java, junit, jaxb, mockito

I am writing a `JUnit` for a method which unmarshalling an `Object`. It is throwing `IllegalArgumentException` while unmarshalling the Object.I cannot post the entire method.

Method under test

```
public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext, ClientResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();
    String contentType = headers.getFirst( CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER );

    if( contentType != null && contentType.startsWith( TEXT_XML ) ) {
        if( 200 == responseContext.getStatus() ) {
            if( requestContext.getUri().toString().contains( "Policy/Retrieve" ) ) {
                try {
                    GetPolicyResponse p = (GetPolicyResponse)EISClientJAXBContextFactory.getUnmarshaller( GetPolicyResponse.class ).unmarshal( responseContext.getEntityStream() );

}
```

While debugging I found that `is` is null but I am passing `inputStream`

```
public final Object unmarshal( java.io.InputStream is )
    throws JAXBException {

    if( is == null ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            Messages.format( Messages.MUST_NOT_BE_NULL, "is" ) );
    }

    InputSource isrc = new InputSource( is );
    return unmarshal( isrc );
}
```

JUnit

```
@Test
public void testPersonalAutoDriver() throws Exception {
 ClientRequestContext requestContext = mock(ClientRequestContext.class);
    ClientResponseContext responseContext = mock(ClientResponseContext.class);
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = mock(MultivaluedMap.class);
    URI uri = new URI("Policy/Retrieve");
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = mock(Unmarshaller.class);

    when( responseContext.getHeaders() ).thenReturn( headers );
    when( headers.getFirst(Mockito.eq( "Content-Type" )) ).thenReturn( "text/xml" );
    when( responseContext.getStatus() ).thenReturn( 200 );
    when( requestContext.getUri()).thenReturn(uri);

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(GetPolicyResponse.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

    Policy policy = new Policy();
    policy.setPolicyType( PolicyTypeEnum.PERSONAL_AUTO );

    GetPolicyResponse policyResponse = new GetPolicyResponse();
    policyResponse.setPolicy(policy);

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.marshal( policyResponse, writer );
    System.out.println( "**** Object Marshalled Successfully ****" );

    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(writer.toString().getBytes());
    when(unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream)).thenReturn(policyResponse);

//  EISClientJAXBContextFactory.getUnmarshaller( GetPolicyResponse.class );
//  Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
//  GetPolicyResponse policyResponse2 = ( GetPolicyResponse ) unmarshaller.unmarshal( inputStream );

//  assertNotNull(policyResponse2);

    filter.filter( requestContext, responseContext );
    System.out.println( "**** Object Unmarshalled Successfully ****" );
}
```

Comment: I also mentioned that I am passing an argument but still it is giving me the same error.

Comment: If I knew that I am passing then why would I ask this question. I know null throws NPE but here I am unable to identify. If you have identified the issue let me know.

Comment: When it reaches to unmarshall method. is shows null.

Comment: Yes it contains the xml.

Comment: writer = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:GetPolicyResponse xmlns:ns2="http://response.mercuryinsurance.com"><policy><policyType>PersonalAuto</policyType></policy></ns2:GetPolicyResponse>

Comment: No, I've commented out those lines because I tried another way but it didn't work that way either.

Comment: Where do you tell the code to use your mocked unmarshaller?

Comment: I am not sure. I am assuming when I invoke the unmarshal method using mocked unmarshaller object.

Comment: At the moment you have created an unmarshaller object but it will not be used. You need to get `(GetPolicyResponse)EISClientJAXBContextFactory.getUnmarshaller` to return your unmarshaller object - which is not trivial ( if you are using Mockito - as it appears to me you are). Mockito can't mock static methods, but a mixture of PowerMock and mockito can. Google "mockito mock static methods" - it's fairly complex though

Comment: I know PowerMock would make it even harder therefore I was trying to keep it simple.

Comment: Well I think you've had it .. if you want to execute the line `GetPolicyResponse p = (GetPolicyResponse)EISClientJAXBContextFactory.getUnmarshaller( GetPolicyResponse.class ).unmarshal( responseContext.getEntityStream() );`, then you're going to need to use a mocking framework that will mock static methods

Comment: This may help a bit ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083432/mock-objects-calling-final-classes-static-methods-with-mockito/17084152#17084152

Comment: Thanks Dave, Ii think this is the only route to go with.

Comment: It worked. PowerMock with Mockito took care of it. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

`EISClientJAXBContextFactory.getUnmarshaller( GetPolicyResponse.class )` is a static method. You can't mock static methods using Mockito.