# How to enable final class mocking with mockito in eclipse project?

Tags: mockito

I am using **mockito-core-2.7.21** in a maven project and it is working as expected.

But to enable mocking of final class I created a file `mockito-extensions\org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` under my source folder and added the text `mock-maker-inline`.

As per https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final and also [Mock final class with Mockito 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979402/mock-final-class-with-mockito-2), it should allow me to mock final classes but when i running my junit test I am getting the below error:

Java Version: 1.8

OS: Windows 10

Junit: 4 and 5(I tried both)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:66)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:186)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:180)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1729)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1642)
    at siemens.esd.grpc.services.UTCreateModuleServiceTest.testCreateBlockInterface(UTCreateModuleServiceTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration@6f75e721
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:101)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:45)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:18)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.GlobalConfiguration.tryGetPluginAnnotationEngine(GlobalConfiguration.java:55)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:68)
    at siemens.esd.grpc.services.UTCreateModuleServiceTest.setUp(UTCreateModuleServiceTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker. (This mock maker is not supported on Android.)

Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 25.181-b13
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 1.8.0_181-b13
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows 10
OS version         : 10.0

    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:96)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No compatible attachment provider is not available
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:347)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:332)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:300)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:286)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<clinit>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:102)
    ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After struggling I found the problem is with the java library available in your java build path.
If you have JRE library in you java build path instead of JDK library then `bytebuddy` utility is throwing this issue.

Hence the solution to the problem is use **JDK library instead of JRE library**.

Comment: Some forums claim that the dependency on JDK is relaxed if you are on the newer version of `bytebuddy` and JDK 11 or higher.

Comment: Thank you for removing a headache. In my case Intellij had somehow switched from a JDK to JRE