# How to mock final class with Mockito 2 on Java Module in Android project?

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito, kotlin

I have a [Android Clean Architecture project](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture) write in Kotlin with 3 modules:

- data (Android Library)
- domaine (Java Library)
- presentation (Android Application)

**The 3 modules each have unit tests written with junit**. But with Kotlin every class is final by default. I quickly had the problem: **How to mock a final class with mockito**

It's now possible with [Mockito 2](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable)

It can be done via the mockito extension mechanism by creating the file `/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing a single line:

```
mock-maker-inline
```

> This solution works very well on data module (Android Library) and
>   presentation module (Android Application) **but doesn't work on my
>   domaine module (Java Library)**.

I know that this question has already been asked ([How to mock a final class with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito), [Mock objects calling final classes static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083432/mock-objects-calling-final-classes-static-methods-with-mockito)), but I didn't find the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work in that module? You have the file for `mock-maker-inline` created, and it's still giving you the error about mocking final classes?

Comment: @zsmb13 yes I have the following error : "Mockito cannot mock/spy because : final class"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the inline mocking method by default, by changing your Gradle dependency from the normal Mockito dependency:

```
compile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockito_version"
```

... to the following:

```
compile "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockito_version"
```

This way you won't have to rely on activating inline mocking with the "file in the resources folder" method, which I have found to be flaky sometimes.

Comment: my saviour. :DD

Comment: Is this also works for Android dependency?
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.27.0'

Answer (score 0):

Mockito's MockMaker can only be used for unit tests (run on JVM). For those who are having problems with mocking Kotlin classes in instrumentation tests (androidTest), try using the [DexOpener](https://github.com/tmurakami/dexopener) library. It makes Kotlin classes, properties and methods `open`, which allows their mocking.