# Mocked Object with Mockito Kotlin Not Stubbing Method

Tags: android, mockito, kotlin

I have the following code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class OnboardingViewModelTest {

    @Mock lateinit var authService : AuthService
    lateinit var internetProvider: InternetStatusProvider
    private lateinit var viewModel: OnboardingViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        internetProvider = mock()
        whenever(internetProvider.hasInternet()).thenReturn(true)
    }
```

The constructor of `InternetStatusProvider` looks like so:

`InternetStatusProvider(context:Context)`

I am getting a `NullPointerException` when stubbing the `internetProvider.hasInternet()` method because that method's implementation uses the `context` passed in the constructor and the real method is being called?

What am I missing here? the whole point is to stub the real implementation of this method?

Comment: What is the signature of the `hasInternet()` function? If it is not `open`, then the call `internetProvider.hasInternert()` will be executed, since Mockito cannot stub a final method.

Comment: Genius, should have been pretty obvious I guess. So stubbed methods need to be open... Not sure I like this. Please submit this as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mockito cannot stub final methods. If you try to execute a final method from a mocked instance, the real code will be executed. Since Kotlin's functions are `final` by default, you'd have to add the `open` modifier to the function.

There is also an [incubating feature](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable) in Mockito that *does* allow mocking of final classes and methods, which may be worth a look.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43310572/4465208) an easy way to start using the inline version of Mockito.