# What is java equivalent of Kotlin's Function Types?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, kotlin

I have code in `Kotlin` and test code in `Java`. Since `Kotlin` and `Mockito` aren't best friends, I haven't migrated test code to `Kotlin`.

In `Kotlin` I have methods with block types. For example:

```
open fun getProductInfo(resultListener: (List<Deal>)->Unit, errorListener: (Throwable)->Unit)
{
    ...
}
```

Now I want to stub this method in `Java` tests. What's the java equivalent of the types? In other words, what should I write in place of ???s below:

```
doAnswer(invocation -> {
    ??? resultListener = (???) invocation.getArguments()[0];
    // call back resultListener
    return null;
}).when(api).getProductInfo(any(), any());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [*Kotlin in Action*](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action) book:

> The Kotlin standard library defines a series of interfaces, corresponding to different numbers of function arguments: `Function0<R>` (this function takes no arguments), `Function1<P1, R>` (this function takes one argument), and so on. Each interface defines a single invoke method, and calling it will execute the function.

In this case, these two functions are both `Function1` instances, since they are functions that take one parameter:

```
Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
    Function1<List<Deal>, Unit> resultListener =
            (Function1<List<Deal>, Unit>) invocation.getArguments()[0];
    Function1<Throwable, Unit> errorListener =
            (Function1<Throwable, Unit>) invocation.getArguments()[1];

    resultListener.invoke(new ArrayList<>());

    return null;
}).when(api).getProductInfo(any(), any());
```

---

On another note, you could try [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) and the [inline version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43310572/4465208) of Mockito to write your tests in Kotlin as well.

Comment: Thanks, that was it :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not to try in Android Studio or IntelliJ, to get Java code from Kotlin:

- Menu -> Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode
- Click on the -> Decompile Button
- Copy the Java code

This way you can continue your work with Mockito, unfortunately you will get redundant lines of code (not much) because Kotlin deal with bytecode.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this helpful feature :)