# What is Java equivalent to Function0 and Function1 of Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I was trying to implement [Github Link](https://github.com/shetmobile/MeowBottomNavigation) library in my java project. And I don't want to use Kotlin in my project, so I was custom coding the whole library into Java. Any help appreciated. It's hard to convert Kotlin to Java rather the opposite. I have worked with decompiling Kotlin Bytecode, which somewhat helps you to convert it into Java. And that's where it's getting confusing where Function0 and Function1 comes into picture. I also saw this [Question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050723/what-is-java-equivalent-of-kotlins-function-types). But I can't use Kotlin in my project.

Comment: Why you convert it to java? You can use the `Library` in your Java code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is java equivalent of Kotlin's Function Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050723/what-is-java-equivalent-of-kotlins-function-types)

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Its not a personal project. Can't use libraries. And want same animation for bottom nav bar

Comment: @0X0nosugar No it didnt. Actually cant use any Kotlin library or any code into my project. Considering the project as a company task. But thanks for the sharing it. I saw that question before

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent are the Functional Interfaces `Supplier` and `Function`, respectively

They have the same signatures, and are SAM (Single abstract methods), so they are replaceable by an in-line lambda.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces#Suppliers
https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces#Functions